# Empty sharepoint spgridview

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, spgridview

I am using an SPGridView to create lists with custom data in a sharepoint website.

When the list has no data, the list headers get hidden and the following message appears:

> There are no items to show in this view.

How can I still show the headers if there are no items in the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`SPGridView` is inherited from `GridView` and you can use `EmptyDataTemplate` where you can override default behaviour and do whatever you want.